# Oracle 11g XE - remote connection problems (Connect timeout occurred)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-12170

New to Oracle and trying to set up an oracle dev environment with 11g XE. Local connections work fine with sqlplus and SQL Developer - remote connections can't seem to see the database. I've tried various configurations of the files below (with google & oracle docs assistance) on various machines but I can't even get the client to register the existence of the server. My current configuration is as follows:

## Server (ip 192.168.0.51):

### listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.51)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

### tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.51)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

### sqlnet.ora

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

### output of lsnrctl stat

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl stat

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 30-MAR-2015 18:31
:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                30-MAR-2015 17:58:16
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 33 min. 36 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Enterprise\listene
r\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.51)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.51)(PORT=8080
))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

### output of netstat -an | find "1521"

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -an | find "1521"
  TCP    192.168.0.51:1521      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.0.51:1521      192.168.0.51:3280      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.51:3280      192.168.0.51:1521      ESTABLISHED
```

on the server I can connect with the following (don't know if this is meaningful i.e. over tcp):

```
sqlplus <user>/<pass>@192.168.0.51:1521/xe
```

## Client:

on the client the above sqlplus connection attempt results in the following:

```
C:\>sqlplus <user>/<pass>@192.168.0.51:1521/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Mar 30 18:14:17 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

### Using Test-NetConnection

```
PS C:\Users> Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.51 -Port 1521
WARNING: TCP connect to 192.168.0.51:1521 failed


ComputerName           : 192.168.0.51
RemoteAddress          : 192.168.0.51
RemotePort             : 1521
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 192.168.0.88
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 1165 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

### Non-port 1521 diagnostics

```
PS C:\Users> ping 192.168.0.51

Pinging 192.168.0.51 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.51: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.51: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.51: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.51: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.51:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 32ms, Average = 12ms

PS C:\Users> Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.51 -Port 80


ComputerName           : 192.168.0.51
RemoteAddress          : 192.168.0.51
RemotePort             : 80
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 192.168.0.88
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 1920 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : True
```

I've disabled firewalls on both server and client machines.

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Apparently your host is not reachable. What are the results of a normal ping to the IP address? You're connecting with Wifi, is your host connected with a wired connection? Some routers prevent access from wireless to wired network clients. 

Als check:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:45033135081903

Comment: Thanks @NonPlusUltra - I added ping results above, and I have tried on wired/non-wired connections - both seem to work on ports other than 1521. I tried what's recommended in your link, but it seems my version of sqlplus won't recognise the syntax. I'm using

`SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production`

And I tried variations around

`sqlplus <user>/<database>@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.51)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))`

Comment: I think you need single quotes around the TNS part of the connection string: `sqlplus <user>/<database>@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.51)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))'`.  And you may be missing a final closing parentheses.